# Recomposition with set does not happen as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The following is code of a view that displays tags

[image]

The tags are supposed to be unique. `TextField` is simply used to get the user input. The input value is appended to a mutable set upon clicking the add button. When the size is printed it displays the correct value in the console! But for some reason the view does not recompose - it simply suggests that either I am using an incorrect data type (mutable-set) for collecting unique values, or, this is not how a `set` can be made `stateful` in compose.

```
@Composable
fun TagsContent() {
    var tags by remember { mutableStateOf(mutableSetOf<String>()) }
    var tag = ""

    TextFieldWithTrailingIcon("e.g. mytag",
        onValueChange = { textFieldValue -> tag = textFieldValue.text }) {
        AddButton(onClick = {
            if (tag.length > 2) {
                tags.add(tag.lowercase())
            }
            println(tags.size) // prints the size correctly!
        })
    }
    // spacing code
    for (tag in tags) {
        TagText(tag) { tags.remove(tag) } // callback to remove, not relevant here
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(Units.dr_tags_item_sep_pdng.dp))
    }
    // other code
}
```

The view works as expected with `mutableStateListOf<String>()` but not with a set. Please kindly let me know how to use set for this use case where the items need to be unique. It might be possible to recompose the view without using a set, but it is so strange why this simple code does not work with a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MutableSet` is not observable for compose. Therefore there is a point in recreating an immutable set.

```
var tags by remember { mutableStateOf(setOf<String>()) }
var tag = ""

TextFieldWithTrailingIcon("e.g. mytag",
    onValueChange = { textFieldValue -> tag = textFieldValue.text }) {
    AddButton(onClick = {
        if (tag.length > 2) {
            val newSet = tags.toMutableSet()
            newSet.add(tag.lowercase())
            tags.value = newSet.toSet() // converting to immutable set
        }
        println(tags.size)
    })
}
```

Comment: marked it as the answer for the example code, conceptual thing to understand that set needs to be redefined, +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `MutableState<Set<String>>` with a "new" `Set` and not just update the current one in-place (=`tags.add(...)`).

Borrowing this from the ["State and Jetpack Compose"](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables) docs:

> Caution: Using mutable objects such as ArrayList or mutableListOf() as state in Compose causes your users to see incorrect or stale data in your app. Mutable objects that are not observable, such as ArrayList or a mutable data class, are not observable by Compose and don't trigger a recomposition when they change. Instead of using non-observable mutable objects, the recommendation is to use an observable data holder such as State<List> and the immutable listOf().

Comment: interesting document, sadly does not give a basic example to describe this line `the recommendation is to use an observable data holder such as State<List<T>> and the immutable listOf()` the caution should be a separate topic in itself with use cases

Answer (score 1):

Following best practice you can make a ViewModel where you can define a `mutableStateListOf` and observe it in Your UI.

**Let's define a ViewModel First**

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class TextFlowExampleViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val list = mutableStateListOf("")

    fun addText(item : String){
        list.add(item)
    }

}
```

> We have also defined the function which will add the item to the list.

**Usage**

Here we are getting a list from the ViewModel and converting it into the `Set` so it removes the duplicate values and then we display it in `LazyColumn`

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue

@Composable
fun TextFlowExampleScreen(textFlowExampleViewModel: TextFlowExampleViewModel) {

    val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    val listState = textFlowExampleViewModel.list.toSet()

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        TextField(
            placeholder = { Text("Enter your text") },
            value = textState.value, onValueChange = {
                textState.value = it
            },
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                textFlowExampleViewModel.addText(textState.value.text)
            }),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            )
        )
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            items(listState.toList()) { item ->
                Text(text = item)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Note: You can edit code as per your requirements.

**Preview**

[image: preview]